# Consul issue with spring boot 2.0.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I just migrated to latest spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE and started using cloud version "Finchley.RC1". I am using consul as config and service registry/discovery server. But as soon as I start the application it tries to load the config from "localhost:8888" which is for eureka. I configured the consul host and port in application.properties but still I see the same behavior.

What I found by searching that there is a bug in spring cloud consul due to which this is happening and it has been fixed in the following commit which is in 2.0.0.RC1 (Release candidate version).

[Commit URL](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/commit/02d740fdf936914485b00cd5bb5b9911924245a0)

So my question is, there any stable version available right now for spring cloud consul which I can use with latest spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now there is stable version that you can use:

- Spring Cloud Finchley.RELEASE (which includes Spring Cloud Consul 2.0.0.RELEASE)
- Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE

See full list:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Finchley-Release-Notes#finchleyrelease